# Cakephp 3 loading HasOne inside HasMany association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using ***Cakephp 3.2.10***

I am able to load associated data with hasOne association and hasMany association. However, I have one hasOne inside the table associated with hasMany, and that gives error.

I have following tables

1. companies
2. company_revenues
3. currencies
4. states
5. countries.

CompaniesTable class has hasOne associations with states,countries and it works. CompaniesTable has hasMany association with CompanyRevenuesTable, and it works. CompanyRevenues table has a hasOne association with currencies, this gives error.

My relevant Code :

CompaniesTable.php

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;

class CompaniesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->primaryKey('company_id');

        $this->addAssociations(
        [
            'hasOne' =>
            [
                'Countries' =>
                [ 'className' => 'Countries','foreignKey' => 'id','bindingKey' => 'company_country_id' ]
                ,'States' =>
                [ 'className' => 'States','foreignKey' => 'id','bindingKey' => 'company_state_id' ]
                ,'Sectors' =>
                [ 'className' => 'Sectors','foreignKey' => 'id','bindingKey' => 'company_sector_id' ]

            ]
            ,'hasMany' =>
            [
                'CompanyRevenues' =>
                [ 'className' => 'CompanyRevenues','foreignKey' => 'revenue_company_id','bindingKey' => 'company_id' ]
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add( $rules->isUnique(['company_name']) );
        return $rules;
    }


    public function compsTotalCount( Query $query )
    {
        $result = $query->select(['companiesCount' => $query->func()->count('*')])->first();
        return $result;
    }   

    public function findPopular( Query $query )
    {
        $result = $query->where(['times_viewed >' => 10]);
        // debug($result);
        return $result;
    }   
}
?>
```

CompanyRevenuesTable.php

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;

class CompanyRevenuesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('company_revenues');

        $this->addAssociations(
        [
            'hasOne' =>
            [
                'Currencies' =>
                [ 'className' => 'Currencies','foreignKey' => 'id','bindingKey' => 'revenue_currency_id' ]

            ]
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

My CompaniesController.php

profile action

```
public function profile( $id = null )
{
    $company = $this->Companies->find()
                ->where(['company_id' => $id])
                ->contain(['CompanyRevenues'])->first();

    if( ! $this->request->is('ajax') )
    {
        $companyRevenuesTable = TableRegistry::get('CompanyRevenues');
        $companyRevenues = $companyRevenuesTable->find()
                                        ->where(['revenue_company_id' => $company->company_id])
                                        ->contain(['Currencies']);
        debug($companyRevenues);
    }


    if( $this->request->is('ajax') )
    {
        $company = $this->Companies->patchEntity($company, $this->request->data);

        $company->company_last_updated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $ajaxRespArr = array();
        if( $this->Companies->save($company) )
        {
            $ajaxRespArr["result"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $ajaxRespArr["result"] = 0;
        }
        $this->set( 'ajaxRespArr',$ajaxRespArr );
        $this->set('_serialize', ['ajaxRespArr']);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('company', $company);
    }
}
```

The debug on $$companyRevenues

gives error

```
 \plugins\Admin\src\Controller\CompaniesController.php (line 92)

object(Cake\ORM\Query) {
(unable to export object: CompanyRevenues is not associated with Currencies)
 }
```

I think the error is because of _ in my table company_revenues.

Can any one guide me please ?

Actually, in the profiles action, i do not want to load company revenues separately, as they come along with company.

I tried the following originally :

```
$company = $this->Companies->find()
            ->where(['company_id' => $id])
            ->contain(
                    [
                        'CompanyRevenues' => ["Currencies"]
                    ])->first();
```

But that give error :

```
    CompanyRevenues is not associated with Currencies InvalidArgumentException

Could this be caused by using Auto-Tables?

Some of the Table objects in your application were created by instantiating "Cake\ORM\Table" instead of any other specific subclass.

This could be the cause for this exception. Auto-Tables are created for you under the following circumstances:

    The class for the specified table does not exist.
    The Table was created with a typo: TableRegistry::get('Atricles');
    The class file has a typo in the name or incorrect namespace: class Atricles extends Table
    The file containing the class has a typo or incorrect casing: Atricles.php
    The Table was used using associations but the association has a typo: $this->belongsTo('Atricles')
    The table class resides in a Plugin but no plugin notation was used in the association definition.


Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:

    CompanyRevenues
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the reverse relationships as well and see what happens.
By reverse relationships I mean belongsTo in your currencies and companyRevenues classes.

- Currencies belongTo companyRevenues and
- CompanyRevenues belongTo company class.

See what your debugging provides.